# Identity Server 4 redirecting to wrong domain on login with Azure Front Door

Tags: c#, azure, identityserver4, .net-6.0

I have signin application (C# .NET6) which is using Identity Server 4 and it works correctly:

- on local machine
- on virtual machine hosted on IIS
- on Azure App Service with cutom domain
  But right now I am creating new infrastructure where everything will be hidden behind the Azure Front Door and it started to not working correctly.
  One I will launch https://signin.xxx.com/ it will automaticly redirect to https://machine_name.azurewebsites.net/SALogin
  I figure out that this is not issue with Azure Front Door as for other applaictions it is working corretly so it seems that the issue is related with the Identity Server 4

I tryied to find setting in Identity Server 4 documentation to set up our domain but with no luck.

Application shouldn't change the domain and redirect to: https://signin.xxx.com/SALogin

Comment: did you try whitelisting the domain in AllowedCorsOrigins ?

Comment: Do you mean to add an entry to the table ClientCorsOrigin? This does not help as there are no CORS errors but some strange redirects which I need to disable